# Is there a linear relationship between energy production and global horizontal irradiance?

Tags: batteries, energy, solar-energy

I'm an apprentice in data science. I am currently working in a company that produces and installs energy storage systems. One of the clients of this company wants to estimate the loss due to the energy curtailment.

For this purpose, I've used the active power at the exit of inverters and the value of global horizontal irradiance (GHI) for a month, and tried to find a relationship between the energy production and GHI so that I can calculate the loss in periods of curtailment.

What I actually did is sample the GHI with a step of *20 W/m2* for all the values between *0 W/m2* and *1200 W/m2* for everyday of the month, then I took the mean of the active power for all the values that fall into the segments: *[0,20] , [20,40],...* I plotted the active power as a function of the GHI and it gave me the following curve:

[image]

The curve is not quite linear, especially for values of GHI higher than 900 W/m2, so I would like to know if it's correct to assume that there is a linear relationship between the energy produced and the GHI, or are there other things I'm missing.

Comment: Do the inverters have a linear Pin:Pout characteristic? || The term "period of curtailment" could probably benefit from explanation. || How did you derive GHI. This is usually diffuse irradiance + normal irradiance x sun_angle. (see eg [here](https://wiki2.org/en/Solar_irradiance) ). How did you measure this? || I'm surprised at the shape of the upper curve and wonder if maybe your DHI and what the panels "actually see" are different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The photovoltaic effect itself is quite linear (but not 100% due to serial resistance and other effects), You have other factors that comes in on a system.

The major one, is the temperature dependency of the solar array, which is negative for the Pmax and quite important. As the irradiation increases, the temperature on the array does as well, which lower the efficiency of the panels.

Another factor, is that as the irradiation increases, the panel produces more current, and thus produces more losses in the cables, inverter and so forth as Ploss=R*I^2.

The spectral irradiation will also have an impact as c-Si panels are more sensitive in infra-red, lower irradiance in the morning/evening may actually have slightly more efficiency as IR traverse the atmosphere with more ease.

In the end of the day, many factors affects the power output.

Note that 1'200W/m2 is quite rare and only happens in specific weather condition. If you get 1'200W/m2 often you may have a calibration issue.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Actually, the energy storage system is implanted in Guadeloupe, and I often find values higher than 1200 W/m2. I don't know if it's a calibration issue or just a usual thing for islands.

Comment: Usually, it goes beyond 1'000W/m2 when you have a cloudy sky with some clear "holes", as then you sometimes have direct + diffuse from the cloud adding up, but they are short peaks, if you have a clear sky, it shouldn't go much above ~1050W/m2